# How to configure Selenium for IE9 when using HTTPS

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I'm trying to get Selenium tests to work through PHPUnit.  My tests pass in Firefox, but not in IE9.  In IE, no matter what combination of settings I've tried, when the Selenium server is running IE will not go directly to the page, and instead displays "There is a problem with this website's security certificate".
If I shut down Selenium, I can use IE to access the site being tested with no problems.
I've tried telling IE that the CyberVillians cert is OK, I've added the cert to IE's list of certs, and tried various Selenium Server command line options.
For what it's worth, I'm using the very latest Selenium and PHPUnit files (downloaded today).
Any ideas?

Comment: I did a bunch more research last night, and it looks like the answer is to abandon Selenium RC, and go with WebDriver.  I found [this PHP-Webdriver binding](http://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/) that I'll try out today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was indeed to abandon using Selenium RC.
I ended up using [chibimagic's Webdriver for PHP](https://github.com/chibimagic/WebDriver-PHP), and everything works great.  I'll probably end up writing a brokering class to make in interface more like that of  PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase.  That way, I can work up test scripts using Selenium IDE, using their PHP formatter, and then just paste into my unit test.